# jdt batch compiler for no uniform encoding files

Tags: eclipse, ant, ecj

I want to use the jdt compiler in ant to compile my project, but the project with no uniform files, so i try use the home doc encoding flag: [batch compiler usage](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm).

code below:

```
<property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter" />
<property name="compiler.args" value="-encoding UTF-8 src/test/Test.java[GBK]" />
<javac destdir="${bin.dir}" includeantruntime="true" debug="true" failonerror="true" >
   <compilerarg line="${compiler.args}" />
   <src path="${src.dir}" />
   <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

when i run this tasks, it will show error:
Error in D:\src\test\Test.java
   public class Test {

The type Test is already defined.

How can i set the different encoding in each file? Is the path wrong?

Comment: Does `<exclude name="src/test/Test.java"/>` as child element of `<src>` work?

Comment: Yeah, it can works, but it will need compile the src twice, each encoding in the compile.

Comment: I understand that `src/test/Test.java[GBK]` means compile the class with the specified encoding (source + encoding), not only set the encoding for this class. Currently, `Test.java` is specified twice as source, with and without `[GBK]`.

Comment: so i must use the exclue for this case? Compile the source for the diffent encoding.Thansk.